# Flutter chat text align like Whatsapp or Telegram

Tags: flutter, alignment, chat

I'm having trouble figuring this alignment with Flutter.

The right conversion on Whatsapp or Telegram is left-aligned but the date is on the right. If there's space available for the date it is at the end of the same line.[image]

The 1st and 3rd chat lines can be done with `Wrap()` widget. But the 2nd line is not possible with `Wrap()` since the chat text is a separate Widget and fills the full width and doesn't allow the date widget to fit. How would you do this with Flutter?

Comment: are you familiar with `RenderBox`es? this is the right way you should follow (of course you could try some workarounds like measuring the text with `TextPainter` but...)

Comment: I'm not. I'll look it up, thank you.

Comment: a warning: its not an easy way... so maybe first try with `TextPainter` - i know its a workaround but its gonna be easier...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. You not providing a sample code kinda give that away anyway ;)

Comment: i have a well written code for it.. will share it with you tomorrow

Comment: @YashBhansali, thank you I'll wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that you can run in DartPad that might be enough to get you started. It uses a `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` for laying out the child and painting the `ChatBubble`'s chat message as well as the message time and a dummy check mark icon.

To learn more about the `RenderObject` class I can recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqXNGawzSbY&t=2385s). It describes all relevant classes and methods in great depth and helped me a lot to create my first custom `RenderObject`.

[image]

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ExampleChatBubbles(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final DateTime messageTime;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final Icon icon;
  final TextStyle textStyleMessage;
  final TextStyle textStyleMessageTime;
  // The available max width for the chat bubble in percent of the incoming constraints
  final int maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage;

  const ChatBubble({
    Key? key,
    required this.message,
    required this.icon,
    required this.alignment,
    required this.messageTime,
    this.maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage = 80,
    this.textStyleMessage = const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 11,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    this.textStyleMessageTime = const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 11,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  })  : assert(
          maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage <= 100 &&
              maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage >= 50,
          'maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage width must lie between 50 and 100%',
        ),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textSpan = TextSpan(text: message, style: textStyleMessage);
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: textSpan,
      textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    return Align(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 5,
          vertical: 5,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          color: Colors.green.shade200,
        ),
        child: InnerChatBubble(
          maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage: maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage,
          textPainter: textPainter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 15,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(
                  DateFormat('hh:mm').format(messageTime),
                  style: textStyleMessageTime,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                icon
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// By using a SingleChildRenderObjectWidget we have full control about the whole
// layout and painting process.
class InnerChatBubble extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final TextPainter textPainter;
  final int maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage;
  const InnerChatBubble({
    Key? key,
    required this.textPainter,
    required this.maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage,
    Widget? child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderInnerChatBubble(textPainter, maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, RenderInnerChatBubble renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..textPainter = textPainter
      ..maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage = maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage;
  }
}

class RenderInnerChatBubble extends RenderBox
    with RenderObjectWithChildMixin<RenderBox> {
  TextPainter _textPainter;
  int _maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage;
  double _lastLineHeight = 0;

  RenderInnerChatBubble(
      TextPainter textPainter, int maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage)
      : _textPainter = textPainter,
        _maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage = maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage;

  TextPainter get textPainter => _textPainter;
  set textPainter(TextPainter value) {
    if (_textPainter == value) return;
    _textPainter = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  int get maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage => _maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage;
  set maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage(int value) {
    if (_maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage == value) return;
    _maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    // Layout child and calculate size
    size = _performLayout(
      constraints: constraints,
      dry: false,
    );

    // Position child
    final BoxParentData childParentData = child!.parentData as BoxParentData;
    childParentData.offset = Offset(
        size.width - child!.size.width, textPainter.height - _lastLineHeight);
  }

  @override
  Size computeDryLayout(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return _performLayout(constraints: constraints, dry: true);
  }

  Size _performLayout({
    required BoxConstraints constraints,
    required bool dry,
  }) {
    final BoxConstraints constraints =
        this.constraints * (_maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage / 100);

    textPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);
    double height = textPainter.height;
    double width = textPainter.width;
    // Compute the LineMetrics of our textPainter
    final List<ui.LineMetrics> lines = textPainter.computeLineMetrics();
    // We are only interested in the last line's width
    final lastLineWidth = lines.last.width;
    _lastLineHeight = lines.last.height;

    // Layout child and assign size of RenderBox
    if (child != null) {
      late final Size childSize;
      if (!dry) {
        child!.layout(BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth),
            parentUsesSize: true);
        childSize = child!.size;
      } else {
        childSize =
            child!.getDryLayout(BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth));
      }

      final horizontalSpaceExceeded =
          lastLineWidth + childSize.width > constraints.maxWidth;

      if (horizontalSpaceExceeded) {
        height += childSize.height;
        _lastLineHeight = 0;
      } else {
        height += childSize.height - _lastLineHeight;
      }
      if (lines.length == 1 && !horizontalSpaceExceeded) {
        width += childSize.width;
      }
    }
    return Size(width, height);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    // Paint the chat message
    textPainter.paint(context.canvas, offset);
    if (child != null) {
      final parentData = child!.parentData as BoxParentData;
      // Paint the child (i.e. the row with the messageTime and Icon)
      context.paintChild(child!, offset + parentData.offset);
    }
  }
}

class ExampleChatBubbles extends StatelessWidget {
  // Some chat dummy data
  final chatData = [
    [
      'Hi',
      Alignment.centerRight,
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: -100)),
    ],
    [
      'Helloooo?',
      Alignment.centerRight,
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: -60)),
    ],
    [
      'Hi James',
      Alignment.centerLeft,
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: -58)),
    ],
    [
      'Do you want to watch the basketball game tonight? We could order some chinese food :)',
      Alignment.centerRight,
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: -57)),
    ],
    [
      'Sounds great! Let us meet at 7 PM, okay?',
      Alignment.centerLeft,
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: -57)),
    ],
    [
      'See you later!',
      Alignment.centerRight,
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: -55)),
    ],
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: chatData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 5,
            ),
            child: ChatBubble(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.check,
                size: 15,
                color: Colors.grey.shade700,
              ),
              alignment: chatData[index][1] as Alignment,
              message: chatData[index][0] as String,
              messageTime: chatData[index][2] as DateTime,
              // How much of the available width may be consumed by the ChatBubble
              maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage: 75,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The width of the chat bubbles are all the same but I guess that's how you're calculating the remaining space. Either way you've given me more than enough. Thank you :)

Comment: That's one of the great features of the `RenderObject`. You set the height and width of the `RenderBox`. I updated my answer accordingly. You can now set the `maxChatBubbleWidthPercentage` which will define the maximum width of the `ChatBubble` to a percentage of the available `maxWidth` of the incoming constraints. The `ChatBubble` will now only consume as much space as is needed for message & icon.

Comment: Already started learning RenderObject. So grateful for the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@hnnngwdlch thanks for your answer it helped me, with this you have full control over the painter. I slightly modified your code for my purposes maybe it will be useful for someone.

PD: I don't know if declaring the TextPainter inside the RenderObject has significant performance disadvantages, if someone knows please write in the comments.

```
class TextMessageWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final double? spacing;
  
  const TextMessageWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    this.textStyle,
    this.spacing,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderTextMessageWidget(text, textStyle, spacing);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, RenderTextMessageWidget renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..text = text
      ..textStyle = textStyle
      ..spacing = spacing;
  }
}

class RenderTextMessageWidget extends RenderBox with RenderObjectWithChildMixin<RenderBox> {
  String _text;
  TextStyle? _textStyle;
  double? _spacing;

  // With this constants you can modify the final result
  static const double _kOffset = 1.5;
  static const double _kFactor = 0.8;

  RenderTextMessageWidget(
    String text,
    TextStyle? textStyle, 
    double? spacing
  ) : _text = text, _textStyle = textStyle, _spacing = spacing;

  String get text => _text;
  set text(String value) {
    if (_text == value) return;
    _text = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  TextStyle? get textStyle => _textStyle;
  set textStyle(TextStyle? value) {
    if (_textStyle == value) return;
    _textStyle = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  double? get spacing => _spacing;
  set spacing(double? value) {
    if (_spacing == value) return;
    _spacing = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter();

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    size = _performLayout(constraints: constraints, dry: false);

    final BoxParentData childParentData = child!.parentData as BoxParentData;
  
    childParentData.offset = Offset(
      size.width - child!.size.width, 
      size.height - child!.size.height / _kOffset
    );
  }

  @override
  Size computeDryLayout(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return _performLayout(constraints: constraints, dry: true);
  }

  Size _performLayout({required BoxConstraints constraints, required bool dry}) {
    textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: _text, style: _textStyle),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr
    );

    late final double spacing;

    if(_spacing == null){
      spacing = constraints.maxWidth * 0.03;
    } else {
      spacing = _spacing!;
    }

    textPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);

    double height = textPainter.height;
    double width = textPainter.width;
    
    // Compute the LineMetrics of our textPainter
    final List<LineMetrics> lines = textPainter.computeLineMetrics();
    
    // We are only interested in the last line's width
    final lastLineWidth = lines.last.width;

    if(child != null){
      late final Size childSize;
    
      if (!dry) {
        child!.layout(BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth), parentUsesSize: true);
        childSize = child!.size;
      } else {
        childSize = child!.getDryLayout(BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth));
      }

      if(lastLineWidth + spacing > constraints.maxWidth - child!.size.width) {
        height += (childSize.height * _kFactor);
      } else if(lines.length == 1){
        width += childSize.width + spacing;
      }
    }

    return Size(width, height);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    textPainter.paint(context.canvas, offset);
    final parentData = child!.parentData as BoxParentData;
    context.paintChild(child!, offset + parentData.offset);
  }
}
```